# Why does Safari hide my text unless I add opacity .99?

Tags: css, safari

I have some text in my app that Safari (for Mac, Version 10.0 (11602.1.50.0.10)) will not show unless I set the opacity to .99 (there may be other hacks, but I haven't tried to find them all). I can also get the text to appear if I do any fiddling in the styles dev tools panel (e.g. set color to red), though of course the change only persists until I refresh the page. Does anyone know why this is, or it simply a safari bug? The correct text value is present in the HTML if I inspect it with Safari's dev tools. It is visible in Chrome and other browsers.

For context, it is an Ember mobile page and so  the text is substituted by Handlebars.js. We are using sass. I don't think any of this is relevant, but it's included to completeness.

Element's computed properties according to Safari:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-user-select: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 182, 136);
display: block;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-size: 15.333333015441895px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 22px;
letter-spacing: -0.36000001430511475px;
line-height: 23px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-rendering: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 8.46875px;
```

Parent's computed properties according to Safari:

```
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-user-select: none;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
display: flex;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-size: 15.333333015441895px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 32px;
letter-spacing: -0.36000001430511475px;
line-height: 23px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-rendering: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 46.46875px;
```

Comment: I have had issues with text-rendering:auto before since it allows the browser to make educated guesses on how to render the text.

Comment: I've tried replacing the "opacity:99" with various text-rendering options and it was not successful; however, it may be because the browser does not support non-auto values; the computed property has a strikethrough style applied in the inspector, even with !important (this idea supported by MDN's compatibility table).

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? By the way, one thing that `opacity` does is establish a new stacking context, so is it possible that without it, the text was behind a opaque area or something, and the opacity puts it in front? (If so, the same effect could be achieved by giving the text `position:relative` and a `z-index`.